# Busqueda con formulario SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

Mediante un formulario envio los datos por un post a otra pagina y estoy intentando diseñar un código para buscar solo los datos que se han rellenado en el formulario (ya que pueden ir null)

He creado esté codigo:

```
 <?php
      include_once "base_de_datos.php";


         $Etiq = $_POST["Etiq"];
         $RespImp = $_POST["RespImp"];
         $Fec_Inic = $_POST["Fec_Inic"];
         $Fec_Fin= $_POST["Fec_Fin"];
         $User_Cre = $_POST["User_Cre"];
         $User_Com = $_POST["User_Com"];
         $Orig = $_POST["Orig"];
         $P_R_O = $_POST["P_R_O"];
         $Prioridad = $_POST["Prioridad"];
         $Eficaz = $_POST["Eficaz"];
         $User_Resp = $_POST["User_Resp"];
         $Fec_PrevIni = $_POST["Fec_PrevIni"];
         $Fec_PrevFin = $_POST["Fec_PrevFin"];
         $Estado = $_POST["Estado"];
         $Process = $_POST["Process"];
```

Ahora parametrizo la consulta y la automatizo

```
// Compruebo datos que llegan

if (!empty($Etiq) || !empty($RespImp) || !empty($User_Cre) || !empty($User_Com) || !empty($Orig ) ||  !empty($P_R_O) || !empty($Prioridad) || !empty($Eficaz) || !empty($User_Resp) || !empty($Estado) || !empty($Process)) {
    $consulta = "SELECT * , FechaAlt=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Alta, 103), FechaPrev=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Prev, 103), FechaImp=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Imp, 103) FROM IncidenciasAlbeniz  WHERE (Fec_Alta >= '$Fec_Inic'  and Fec_Alta <= '$Fec_Fin') and (Fec_Prev >= '$Fec_PrevIni' and Fec_Prev <=  '$Fec_PrevFin') and '  ";

// Automatizo automaticamente los campos que van al where

    if (!empty($Etiq)) {
        $consulta .= 'Etiqueta1 = "' . $_POST['Etiq'] . '" AND ';
    }
    if (!empty($RespImp)) {
        $consulta .= 'ResponsableImp = "' . $_POST['ResImp'] . '"AND ';
    }
    if (!empty($User_Cre)) {
        $consulta .= 'User_Cre = "' . $_POST['User_Cre'] . '" AND ';
    }

    if (!empty($User_Com)) {
        $consulta .= 'User_Com = "' . $_POST['User_Com'] . '" AND ';
    }
    if (!empty($Orig)) {
        $consulta .= 'Orig = "' . $_POST['Orig'] . '"AND ';
    }
    if (!empty($P_R_O)) {
        $consulta .= 'P_R_O = "' . $_POST['P_R_O'] . '" AND ';
    }

    if (!empty($Prioridad)) {
        $consulta .= 'Prioridad = "' . $_POST['Prioridad'] . '" AND ';
    }
    if (!empty($Eficaz)) {
        $consulta .= 'Eficaz = "' . $_POST['Eficaz'] . '"AND ';
    }
    if (!empty($User_Resp)) {
        $consulta .= 'User_Resp = "' . $_POST['User_Resp'] . '" AND ';
    }
   if (!empty($Estado)) {
        $consulta .= 'Estado = '  . $_POST['Estado'] . '" AND';
    }
    if (!empty($Process)) {
        $consulta .= 'Process= "' . $_POST['Process'] . '" AND ';
    }
    // Retiro el último AND, pues es inservible
    $consulta = rtrim($consulta, ' AND');

// Escribo la consulta para ver donde falla.

    echo $consulta;
} else {
    echo 'No se ha rellenado ningún campo';
}


$sentencia = $base_de_datos->query($consulta);

      $IncidenciasAlbeniz = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      ?>
```

Si meto por ejemplo en la variable Estado= ABIERTA

Sale:

```
$consulta=SELECT * , FechaAlt=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Alta, 103), FechaPrev=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Prev, 103), FechaImp=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Imp, 103) FROM IncidenciasAlbeniz WHERE (Fec_Alta >= '2000-01-01' and Fec_Alta <= '2020-04-22') and (Fec_Prev >= '1800-01-01' and Fec_Prev <= '2020-04-22') and ' Estado = ABIERTA"
```

Y si meto por ejemplo en Estado = ABIERTA y en User_Com= CARLOS TELLERIA

Me sale:

```
$consulta=SELECT * , FechaAlt=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Alta, 103), FechaPrev=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Prev, 103), FechaImp=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Imp, 103) FROM IncidenciasAlbeniz WHERE (Fec_Alta >= '2000-01-01' and Fec_Alta <= '2020-04-22') and (Fec_Prev >= '1800-01-01' and Fec_Prev <= '2020-04-22') and ' User_Com = "CARLOS TELLERIA" AND Estado = ABIERTA"
```

Como vereis no sale escrito el resultado correctamente para SQL SERVER ¿Me podéis ayudar?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

primero veo que en `$consulta = "SELECT * , FechaAlt=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Alta, 103), FechaPrev=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Prev, 103), FechaImp=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Imp, 103) FROM IncidenciasAlbeniz  WHERE (Fec_Alta >= '$Fec_Inic'  and Fec_Alta <= '$Fec_Fin') and (Fec_Prev >= '$Fec_PrevIni' and Fec_Prev <=  '$Fec_PrevFin') and '  ";`
 tienes una comilla simple de mas debes quitarla, luego para concatenar los datos que envias por post debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$consulta .= "Etiqueta1 = '" . $_POST['Etiq'] . "' AND";
```

de esa forma al final tu consulta quedara de la siguiente forma

```
introducir el códSELECT * , FechaAlt=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Alta, 103), FechaPrev=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Prev, 103), FechaImp=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Imp, 103) FROM IncidenciasAlbeniz WHERE (Fec_Alta >= '' and Fec_Alta <= '') and (Fec_Prev >= '' and Fec_Prev <= '') and Etiqueta1 = 'etq1'
```

Espero sea lo que estes buscando sino me puedes escribir para ayudarte a resolver tus dudas.

, saludos.